# How to Insert a New Record Based on Previous Query

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I need to update some columns from the table (stats) & if that fails or succeeds (no matter what the result is) then create a new record in the table (notifications) without using a semicolon (;) Between the 1st & 2nd query

*First Query: *

```
UPDATE stats SET delivered = delivered + 1 WHERE id = 1
```

*Second Query: *

```
INSERT INTO notifications (text) VALUES ('table stats updated')
```

(The example above is not working.)

Please note that

- I cannot use procedures, functions or triggers, only a simple query.
- I cannot use a semicolon (;) between the two queries.
- The update query needs to be executed first.

I've already tried some queries with no result, such as

```
UPDATE stats SET delivered = delivered + 1 WHERE id = 
     (INSERT INTO notifications (text) VALUES ('table stats  updated') RETURNING id)
```

Comment: What client are you using?  The obvious way would be to execute these statements in the same transaction.

Comment: I'm using pgadmin4

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the commands in a single transaction statement then you can use multiple WITHs to execute many commands in a single transaction :

```
WITH query1 AS (
UPDATE stats SET delivered = delivered + 1 WHERE id = 1 RETURNING delivered
),
query2 AS (
    INSERT INTO notifications (text) 
    SELECT  delivered FROM query1 RETURNING id 
)
SELECT * FROM query1 , query2 ;
```

Rules example :

```
CREATE RULE rul_delivered_insertnotification AS ON UPDATE 
     TO delivered WHERE true
     DO (
     INSERT INTO notifications (notification) VALUES (NEW.delivered) ;
     ) ;
     CREATE RULE rul_notification_deliverednotification AS ON INSERT 
     TO notifications WHERE true
     DO (
     SELECT NEW.notification ;
     );
```

The on delivered update below will go to the Rule , insert into notification and then notification will retrieve a select with the field notification inserted.

Table with rules return and no rules on second image:

[image]
[image]

Comment: is there another way to do that without using CTE

Comment: You can use RULES or Triggers also, rules are light weight and complicate due to infinite recursion it means you cannot create a update rule on top of a update query on the same table the same for all other CRUDs.
Triggers will be very easy to do it a little bit more expensive for the database but only impactful on big databases with few space for newer operations.